# Finding adjacent terms

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string:

```
Str1 = "Confidential Design No. PXB1235GHYZ9"
```

This string can also occur in the below variations:

```
Str2 = "Confidential Design No PXB1235GHYZ9"
```

(notice no "." next to No) OR

```
Str3 = "Confidential Design PXB1235GHYZ9"
```

Given the keyword, Design, I need to extract PXB1235GHYZ9. This term is always 12 characters long and is always a mixture of alpha and numbers.

How can I write a generic script to handle all the 3 scenarios using RegEx/Perl? Should I split them using space and then check each term? Or is there an easier way I can extract "PXB1235GHYZ9" given Design in all 3 scenarios?

Comment: Understood.I'm actually commenting back on the question if something worked. I just cannot find the "accept" link or button. Sounds lame - but where is it? I only see: Share: Edit: Delete: Flag: Hide:Help

Comment: Look at the first line of a post.  Look all the way to the left.  there are some up down arrows and/or an outlined checkmark.  Click on those things.  If you click on something and want to undo it, click on the same thing again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str =~ /Confidential Design (No\.? )?([A-Z0-9]{12})/;
```

The term will be $2.

Comment: Or just ``my ($term) = $str =~ /Confidential Design (?:No\.? )?([A-Z0-9]{12})/;``.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
$str =~ /Design +(?:No\.? +)?([A-Za-z0-9]{12})/;
```

Checks for `Design`, optionally followed by `No` or `No.`, followed by 12 alphanumerics (I'm assuming your code-things are alphanumeric), all separated by one or more spaces. The code will end up in `$1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Within the script, I'm just doing a $myStr = $1 and then print $str. Keeps complaining of uninitialized value $1 in print. Meaning, $1 is null, isnt it?

Comment: @simak Are you using the regex *before* you try to use `$1`? The match variables (`$1` and friends) are only defined after you use a regex on something.

Comment: Yes - I'm using $1 after using regex. Exact syntax is: $str ~= /Design +(?:No\.? +)?([A-Za-z0-9]{12})/; $myStr = $1; print $myStr;

Comment: @simak That's odd; go read the regex manuals (I will right now). That *should* work!

Comment: @simak \*epic facepalm\* I used `~=` instead of `=~`... (Clearly it's been too long since I used Perl.) Change that and check.

Comment: Nope, I used the correct one in my code =~ :). Also tried this just with $1 and not assigning it to any variable. Same error.

Comment: @simak At this point it's probably worth a new question.

Comment: Just try this: ``print $str =~ /Design +(?:No\.? +)?(\w{12})/, "\n"`` and see what happens.